# Returning error from controller to AJAX jQuery

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I works with ASP.net MVC and I have get "Error" from belowe my JavaScript code:

This is my AJAX jQuery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var dataId;
    $(".item2 .small-img").click(function () {

        dataId = $(this).data("id");
        var url = '@Url.Action("DecorationTest", "Carpet")' + "?Id=" + dataId + "&title=" + '@Url.ToFriendlyUrl(Model.Title.ToString())';
        $('#dateLink').prop('href', url);
        
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Carpet/CheckCarpet',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'Json',
                data: '{"CarpetImageid":"' + dataId + '"}',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.Success == false)
                        $('#dateLink').hide();
                    else
                        $('#dateLink').show();
                    alert("Success");

                },
                error: function (errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
```

and this is a controller code:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckCarpet(int CarpetImageid)
    {
        bool DecorShow = false;

        DecorShow = db.Images.Where(x => x.Id == CarpetImageid).FirstOrDefault().DecorTest;
        return Json(new JsonData { Success= DecorShow });
    }
```

what's the reason? Someone knows?

Comment: what says your error

Comment: @erdiyılmaz show alert with message: Error

Comment: @erdiyılmaz The same thing I wrote in the error part

Comment: use alert(errorThrown) in error part

Comment: @erdiyılmaz Error says : [object Object]

Comment: try alert(errorThrown.d)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218430/discussion-between-erdi-yilmaz-and-mohadeseh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.i change `url` to `@Url.Action("CheckCarpet", "Carpet")` and fixed.

```
$(".small-img").click(function () {
            dataId = $(this).data("id");
            var url = '@Url.Action("DecorationTest", "Carpet")' + "?Id=" + dataId + "&title=" + '@Url.ToFriendlyUrl(Model.Title.ToString())';
            $('#dateLink').attr('href', url);

        $.ajax({
            url:'@Url.Action("CheckCarpet", "Carpet")',
            type: 'Post',
            dataType: 'Json',
            data: '{"CarpetImageid":"' + dataId + '"}',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.Success == false) {
                    $('#dateLink').hide();
                    $('.p2').hide();
                }
                else {
                    $('#dateLink').show();
                    $('.p2').show();
                }

            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.d);
            }
        });
    });
```